# Decoding JSON with element named self

Tags: json, swift, codable

In Swift 5.1 I want to decode a JSON document containing an element named self. It is a HAL document, so I cannot change the element name.

The JSON is like this;

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "eventList": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "datetime": "2020-04-20T20:00:00",
        "description": "...",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://.../events/1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "datetime": "2020-04-19T08:30:00",
        "description": "...",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://.../events/2"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://.../events"
    }
  }
}
```

My domain model looks like this

```
struct JSonRootElement: Codable {
    var _embedded: JsonEmbedded
}

struct JsonEmbedded: Codable {
    var eventList: [JsonEvent]
}

struct JsonEvent: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var datetime: String
    var description: String
    var _links: JsonHalLink
}

struct JsonHalLink: Codable {
    var self: JsonHalSelfLink
}

struct JsonHalSelfLink: Codable {
    var href: String
}
```

Of course, the JsonHalLink struct contains a forbidden name. I can rename the variable name, but how to tell Swift it has to read the self element from JSON?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use back-ticks (`) around restricted keywords to use them as variable names.

```
struct JsonHalLink: Codable {
    let `self`: JsonHalSelfLink
}
```

Otherwise, if you want your variable to have a different name than its JSON key, you can declare a `CodingKey` conformant `enum` to define a mapping between your property names and JSON keys.

```
struct JsonHalLink: Codable {
    let varName: JsonHalSelfLink

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case varName = "self"
    }
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but you should only declare properties as mutable (`var`) when they actually need to be mutable. If they are never mutated, simply declare them as immutable (`let`).